# How I make a multiboot DVD using Easyboot with Deepin and Prime OS (or Phoenix OS) inside

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, dvd

I'm trying to make a Muiltiboot DVD using Easyboot with Deepin 15 and Prime OS. Please help to make then bootable and working the installer.

Here is the list of commands that I tried in Easyboot:

```
run /ezboot/isofiles/deepin15/deepin15.iso
run /ezboot/isofiles/deepin15/deepin15.img (I've used the script easyboot-iso with Winbuilder [balder script])
bcdw /ezboot/isofiles/deepin15/deepin15.iso
bcdw /ezboot/isofiles/deepin15/deepin15.img
isolinux /isolinux/isolinux.cfg (I've tried it extracted too into the Disk 1 folder in Easyboot)
bcdw /syslinux/isolinux.cfg (This one have worked the boot, but it doesn't open the Deepin installer after that)
```

I'm using Winbuilder script from balder to try make then work. Below is the log from winbuider. I'm try to make a grub image (kicker-image script form balder) [*.img].

Here is the menu.lst code using to generate the grub .img (script) in the Winbuilder:

```
set isofile="/ezboot/ISOFILES/DEEPIN15/DEEPIN15.iso"
search --file $isofile --set=root
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz.efi boot=live union=overlay username=user quiet live-config findiso=$isofile locales=zh_CN.UTF-8
initrd (loop)/live/initrd.lz
boot
```

Here is the log in the Easyboot kicker-image script in Winbuilder:

> [Script] Processing section: [Process-Grub] in file: [EasyBoot kicker-image]

```
 File [%BaseDir%\Projects\LiveXP\EasyBoot\easyboot-kicker-image.script] Version [3]
 [Info] Menu text lines
 [Success] IF - [0.32Mb] is equal to: [0.32Mb] evaluated string: [If,%pScrollBox1%,EQUAL,0.32Mb,Set,%size%,2]
 [Success] SetVar - Sucessfuly changed the value of [%size%] to: [2]
 [Ignore] IF - [0.32Mb] is not equal to: [1.44Mb] evaluated string: [If,%pScrollBox1%,EQUAL,1.44Mb,Set,%size%,6]
 [Ignore] IF - [0.32Mb] is not equal to: [2.88Mb] evaluated string: [If,%pScrollBox1%,EQUAL,2.88Mb,Set,%size%,7]
 [Success] DirMake - Created directory: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage]
 [Success] DirMake - Created directory: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu]
 [Success] ExtractAllFiles - [%BaseDir%\Projects\LiveXP\EasyBoot\easyboot-kicker-image.script] Section [Folder1] to: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage]
 [Success] ExtractAllFiles - [%BaseDir%\Projects\LiveXP\EasyBoot\easyboot-kicker-image.script] Section [Folder2] to: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu]
 [Success] TxtAddLine - Added line: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst] line: [set isofile=] Option:"/ezboot/ISOFILES/DEEPIN15/DEEPIN15.iso"""
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst search --file $isofile --set=root PLACE 1 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst search#$s--file#$s$isofile#$s--set=root PLACE 1 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst loopback loop $isofile PLACE 2 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst loopback#$sloop#$s$isofile PLACE 2 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz.efi boot=live union=overlay username=user quiet live-config findiso=$isofile locales=zh_CN.UTF-8 PLACE 3 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst linux#$s(loop)/live/vmlinuz.efi#$sboot=live#$sunion=overlay#$susername=user#$squiet#$slive-config#$sfindiso=$isofile#$slocales=zh_CN.UTF-8 PLACE 3 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst initrd (loop)/live/initrd.lz PLACE 4 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst initrd#$s(loop)/live/initrd.lz PLACE 4 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst boot PLACE 5 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst boot PLACE 5 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 6 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 6 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 7 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 7 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 8 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 8 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 9 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 9 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 10 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 10 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 11 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 11 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 12 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 12 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 13 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 13 ]
[Warning] Error - [TXTAddLine %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 14 %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu\menu.lst PLACE 14 ]
 [Success] ShellExecute: [Open] using: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\bfi.exe] with parameters: [ -v -b=%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\grubmbr -t=2 -f=%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\deepin.img %BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\menu]
 [Ignore] IF - [False] is not equal to: [true] evaluated string: [if,%pCheckBox1%,Equal,true,Run,%ScriptFile%,Gzipgrub]
 [Success] TXTReplace - Replaced strings in file: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\memdisk.txt] string [anonymous.img.gz] with string: [deepin.img]
 [Success] TXTReplace - Replaced strings in file: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\memdisk.txt] string [memdisk] with string: [run]
 [Success] ShellExecute: [Open] using: [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\memdisk.txt]
 [Ignore] IF - File does not exist: [C:\EasyBoot\disk1\EZBOOT\deepin.img] evaluated string: [If,EXISTFILE,%pFileBox1%\%pTextBox16%.img,FileDelete,%pFileBox1%\%pTextBox16%.img]
 [Success] FileCopy - Copied [%BaseDir%\Temp\newimage\deepin.img] to: [C:\EasyBoot\disk1\EZBOOT]
 [Success] FileDelete - Sucessfully deleted [%BaseDir%\Temp\*.*]
[Warning] ExitMessage

 [Done] Finished processing script: EasyBoot kicker-image (easyboot-kicker-image.script)
 [Clock] Script time: 8 seconds and 827 milliseconds

 [Done] Script has been sucessfully processed!
```